# Spring calling 'destroy' method on session/request scoped beans

Tags: spring, session, request

How does Spring know when to call 'destory' method on a session/request scoped bean (in other words, how does it detect that the concerned bean is going out of scope)?

I read somewhere that it uses request/session listeners to be notified of these events. But these listners need to be defined in web.xml, and there's no mention of defining such listeners in Spring literature. So how does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` does it. It uses own code, e.g. the `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes#registerDestructionCallback` callback list functionality to register all these scoped beans.

Comment: Could you pl. elaborate or mention the relevant links?

Comment: @shrini1000 I'm just reading the source code of spring 2.5. E.g. here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/2.5.6/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#941

Answer (score 2):

> and there's no mention of defining such listeners in Spring literature

Oh, there is:

> To support the scoping of beans at the `request`, `session`, and global session levels (web-scoped beans), some minor initial configuration is required before you define your beans.[...]
>
> If you use a Servlet 2.4+ web container, [...] you need to add the following `javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener` to the declarations in your web applications web.xml file[...]

From: [4.5.4.1 Initial web configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-web-configuration).

Also note that Spring does **not** call destroy on `prototype`-scoped beans.

Comment: If we're using DispatcherServlet or DispatcherPortlet, it says: "DispatcherServlet and DispatcherPortlet already expose all relevant state." but does not go into details as to how and what.

Comment: @shrini1000: `DispatcherServlet` is used mainly for Spring MVC. This means that if you are within Spring MVC controller, you don't need these listeners.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the interface `DisposableBean` and `InitializingBean` for session scoped bean.

The `org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean` interface allows a bean to perform initialization work after all necessary properties on the bean have been set by the container. The InitializingBean interface specifies a single method `afterPropertiesSet()`.

Implementing the `org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean` interface allows a bean to get a callback when the container containing it is destroyed. The DisposableBean interface specifies a single method `destroy()`.

Read more about it here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-nature